# Rodar javascript sem chamar no html

Tags: javascript, css

Ola

Eu preciso alterar a cor de fundo de uma div, estou tentando mas não funciona oque pode estar errado ?

Meu código:

```
window.onresize = function() {
  var w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
  if (w < 800) {
    getElementById("top").style.background-color = "#FFFFFF";
  }
};
```

Obrigado

Comment: Quando quer manipular algum elemento do DOM(Document Object Model) vc primeiro precisa acessá-lo certo? No caso o documento, ou seja, **document.getElementById(...**

Comment: Além do comentário do @LeAndrade, precisa mudar o `style.background-color` para `style.backgroundColor `

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem 2 erros em seu código:

- Antes do getElementById deverá ter `document.`
- background-color não pode ter caracteres especiais igual CSS, sempre utilize [camelCase](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase#:%7E:text=CamelCase%20%C3%A9%20a%20denomina%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20em,defini%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20de%20classes%20e%20objetos.). Exemplo: `backgroundColor`

E por fim, seu código ficará assim:

```js
window.onresize = function() {
  var w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
  if (w < 800) {
    document.getElementById("top").style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
  }
};
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte

```html
<div id="top" style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color:red"></div>
<script>
    window.onresize = function() {
        const top = document.getElementById('top');
        const red = '#ff0000';
        const green = '#4CAF50';        
        var w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
        top.style.backgroundColor = w <= 800 ? red: green;
        /*
        if (w <= 800)
            top.style.backgroundColor = "#4CAF50";
        else if (w > 501)
            top.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
        */
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. errado `getElementById` correto `document.getElementById`
2. errado `background-color` correto `backgroundColor`

```js
    function sizeOfThings(){
      var windowWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;;

     alert('Width  =  '+windowWidth+ " é menor que 800, portanto vai ficar azul");
      
      document.getElementById('top').innerHTML = "Width = "+ windowWidth;

      if (windowWidth < 800) {
        document.getElementById('top').style.backgroundColor = "blue"
      }

    };
    
sizeOfThings();
```

```html
    <h1 id="top" style="background-color: #FF0000">cor inicial deste titulo é vermelho</h1>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.